# How to rewrite 'select top N syntax' in mysql?

Tags: mysql

With the help of many comments, I could make a query for selecting top 2 score for each subject for each person.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test_result AS t
WHERE t.id In (SELECT TOP 2 id
               FROM test_result
               WHERE student = t.student 
               AND subject = t.subject
               ORDER BY score desc, id asc)
ORDER BY t.student asc, t.score asc;
```

This time I want to make this query in MYSQL.
Unfortunately, there isn't top syntax in MYSQL.
So, I searched the Internet and I finally get an answer like this:

```
set @num := 0, @type := '';

select type, variety, price
from (
   select type, variety, price,
      @num := if(@type = type, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @type := type as dummy
  from fruits
  order by type, price
) as x where x.row_number <= 2;
```

Can anyone help me how to add one more condition on this query?

**I'm sorry that I wasn't clear enough. 
I want the result to be "top 2 prices of each variety of each type of fruits without using 'group by' clause."**

Comment: Maybe, if you tell us what it is.

Comment: There's [`LIMIT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#idm139723772517392) in MySQL